# Simon Says won't show sequence

Tags: java, methods, jframe, jpanel, jcomponent

Below is a Simon Says program I am working on. Right now it only displays a gray frame. I added in a keyListener to see if i could make the arcs light up.I wanted to display a flash animation sequence. Why isn't this working?

```
public class SimonShape extends JFrame implements KeyListener, ActionListener      {  

private JFrame f;
private JPanel p;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new SimonShape();
}

public SimonShape() {

    f = new JFrame("Simon Says");
    f.setSize(500, 500);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    DrawStuff draw = new DrawStuff();

    p = new JPanel();
    p.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    p.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    draw.playSequence();
    p.add(draw, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    // initiates the sequence
    f.add(p);
    f.addKeyListener(this);
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // positions the frame in the middle of
                                    // the screen


    f.setVisible(true);

}

public class DrawStuff extends JComponent {

    Color COLOR1;
    Color COLOR2;
    Color COLOR3;
    Color COLOR4;

    public void playSequence() {

        ArrayList<Integer> Computer = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> Player = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        int compPick, compPick2, compPick3, compPick4;

        Random gen = new Random();

        compPick = gen.nextInt(4);
        compPick2 = gen.nextInt(4);
        compPick3 = gen.nextInt(4);
        compPick4 = gen.nextInt(4);

        Computer.add(compPick);
        Computer.add(compPick4);
        Computer.add(compPick2);
        Computer.add(compPick3);
        
        for (int i = 0; i < Computer.size(); i++) {

            if (Computer.get(i) == 0) {
                COLOR1 = Color.GREEN.brighter();
                repaint();
            } else if (Computer.get(i) == 1) {
                COLOR2 = Color.BLUE.darker();
                repaint();

            } else if (Computer.get(i) == 2) {
                COLOR3 = Color.RED.darker();
                repaint();

            } else if (Computer.get(i) == 3) {
                COLOR4 = Color.YELLOW.brighter();
                repaint();
            }
        }

    }

}

public int flash = 0;

public void paint(Graphics g) {

    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    Graphics2D g3 = (Graphics2D) g;
    Graphics2D g4 = (Graphics2D) g;
    Graphics2D g5 = (Graphics2D) g;

    // assume d == 145 && e == 90

    if (flash == 1) {
        g2.setPaint(Color.GREEN);
    } else {
        g2.setPaint(Color.GREEN.darker());

    }
    g2.fill(new Arc2D.Double(150, 150, 200, 200, 145, 90, Arc2D.PIE));
    if (flash == 2) {
        g3.setPaint(Color.BLUE);
    } else {
        g3.setPaint(Color.BLUE.darker());
    }
    g3.fill(new Arc2D.Double(150, 150, 200, 200, 235, 90, Arc2D.PIE));

    if (flash == 3) {
        g4.setPaint(Color.RED);
    } else {
        g4.setPaint(Color.RED.darker());
    }
    g4.fill(new Arc2D.Double(150, 150, 200, 200, 325, 90, Arc2D.PIE));
    if (flash == 4) {
        g5.setPaint(Color.YELLOW);
    } else {
        g4.setPaint(Color.YELLOW.darker());
    }
    g5.fill(new Arc2D.Double(150, 150, 200, 200, 55, 90, Arc2D.PIE));

}
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

    int event = e.getKeyCode();

    if (event == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
        flash = 1;
    }
    if (event == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
        flash = 2;
    }
    if (event == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
        flash = 3;
    }
    if (event == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
        flash = 4;
    }
}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {//not used

}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {//not used

}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {//not used 

}

}
```

Comment: An aside: Capitalizing the first letter of your variable names (like `int CompPick;`) is generally bad practice and should only be used for class names. I'd use camel-case (`int compPick;`).

Comment: Why are you creating another instance of `DrawStuff` in your `playSequence()` method? You can access `COLOR1` and the other variables without it, and it won't show up anyway because that instance isn't added to your JFrame.

Comment: Also, `gen.nextInt(4)` will return a random number from 0-3, so you should be checking for those instead of 1-4.

Comment: Ok, I made those changes and added the sequence to the frame inside my constructor, but for some reason I'm getting the same results.

Comment: You just need to add your original `DrawStuff` to the `JPanel` which is added to the `JFrame` like you do in `SimonShape()`. Take out the `DrawStuff ds = new DrawStuff();` in `playSequence()` and just refer to `ds.COLOR1` as `COLOR1` (same for other variables). You also don't need to return `ds`, so you can remove that and make `playSequence` return `void`.

Comment: I don't really know what you're expecting to show up though. It's just going to be a static pie with maybe one of the colors changed. If you want to see an animation flashing a sequence, then you'll need to do more.

Comment: I wanted to see an animation flashing sequence. What more do i need to do?

Comment: First of all you're adding the same random number 4 times, so you'll need to change that if you want variety. Then you should do something like: change color to darker, repaint(), wait 1 second, change the color back, repaint() for each iteration in your for-loop.

Comment: Ok I made some changes that should have worked but I'm only getting a gray frame now. Can you look and see what the problem may be?

Answer (score 0):

When creating any Swing GUI, you should always use the [model / view / controller pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller).  This pattern allows you to separate your concerns and focus on one part of the GUI at a time.

Divide and conquer.

Here's the GUI I created.

[image: Simon Says GUI]

The first thing I did was create a model for the game.  The GameModel class is a plain Java object that holds the computer sequence and the player sequence.

```
public class GameModel {

    private List<Integer> computerSequence;
    private List<Integer> playerSequence;

    private Random random;

    public GameModel() {
        this.computerSequence = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        this.playerSequence = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        this.random = new Random();
    }

    public void addToComputerSequence() {
        computerSequence.add(Integer.valueOf(random.nextInt(4)));
    }
    
    public void clearComputerSequence() {
        computerSequence.clear();
    }

    public List<Integer> getComputerSequence() {
        return computerSequence;
    }
    
    public void clearPlayerSequence() {
        playerSequence.clear();
    }

    public void addToPlayerSequence(int number) {
        playerSequence.add(Integer.valueOf(number));
    }

    public boolean doSequencesMatch() {
        if (computerSequence.size() == playerSequence.size()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < computerSequence.size(); i++) {
                int computer = computerSequence.get(i);
                int player = playerSequence.get(i);
                if (computer != player) {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

}
```

The model class allows us to add to the computer sequence, add to the player sequence, and determine if the computer and player sequence match.

Next, we need a model class to hold the 4 slices of the circle.  The ArcModel class is another plain Java object that holds a slice.

```
public class ArcModel {

    private final int closureType;

    private final double startingAngle;
    private final double extent;

    private Color color;
    private final Color originalColor;

    private final Rectangle rectangle;

    public ArcModel(Color color, Rectangle rectangle, double startingAngle,
            double extent, int closureType) {
        this.color = color;
        this.originalColor = color;
        this.rectangle = rectangle;
        this.startingAngle = startingAngle;
        this.extent = extent;
        this.closureType = closureType;
    }

    public int getClosureType() {
        return closureType;
    }

    public double getStartingAngle() {
        return startingAngle;
    }

    public double getExtent() {
        return extent;
    }

    public Rectangle getRectangle() {
        return rectangle;
    }

    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void brighterColor() {
        this.color = Color.WHITE;
    }

    public void darkerColor() {
        this.color = originalColor;
    }

}
```

In addition to the getters and setters, we have a method to brighten the color and a method to darken the color.  I've set the bright color to white to make it more easily visible.

Now that we've created the model classes, let's look at the view classes.  The first view class is the DrawingPanel class.

```
public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 70146219705119575L;

    private List<ArcModel> segments;

    public DrawingPanel() {
        this.segments = new ArrayList<ArcModel>();

        int margin = 50;
        int diameter = 300;
        Rectangle r = new Rectangle(margin, margin, diameter, diameter);

        segments.add(new ArcModel(Color.GREEN, r, 180, 90, Arc2D.PIE));
        segments.add(new ArcModel(Color.BLUE, r, 270, 90, Arc2D.PIE));
        segments.add(new ArcModel(Color.RED, r, 360, 90, Arc2D.PIE));
        segments.add(new ArcModel(Color.YELLOW, r, 90, 90, Arc2D.PIE));

        int width = diameter + margin + margin;
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, width));
    }

    public void brighterArcModelColor(int index) {
        segments.get(index).brighterColor();
        repaint();
    }

    public void darkerArcModelColor(int index) {
        segments.get(index).darkerColor();
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        for (ArcModel arcModel : segments) {
            g2d.setPaint(arcModel.getColor());
            Rectangle r = arcModel.getRectangle();
            g2d.fill(new Arc2D.Double(r.getX(), r.getY(), r.getWidth(), r
                    .getHeight(), arcModel.getStartingAngle(), arcModel
                    .getExtent(), arcModel.getClosureType()));
        }
    }

}
```

Here, we create a List of ArcModel segments.  We set the size of the drawing panel based on the margin and diameter of the circle we want to create with the segments.

We have two methods, one for brightening a color of a segment, and another for darkening a color of a segment.

We do the drawing in the paintComponent method.  Since we created the ArcModel class, the actual drawing is straightforward.  The paintComponent method does nothing but draw the pie slices of the circle.

Next, we look at the main SimonShape class.  This class creates the game model and creates the GUI.

```
public class SimonShape implements Runnable {

    private GameModel gameModel;

    private JFrame frame;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new SimonShape());
    }

    public SimonShape() {
        this.gameModel = new GameModel();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        frame = new JFrame("Simon Says");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        DrawingPanel drawingPanel = new DrawingPanel();
        frame.add(drawingPanel);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        GameRunnable runnable = new GameRunnable(drawingPanel, gameModel);
        new Thread(runnable).start();
    }
}
```

The last two lines of the run method create the animation.

The controller class is the GameRunnable class.  I wrote enough code to have the computer pick 10 random segments, and display the sequence of the segments.  I'm leaving the rest of the game code up to you.  It will go in the GameRunnable class.

```
public class GameRunnable implements Runnable {

    private volatile boolean running;

    private DrawingPanel drawingPanel;

    private GameModel gameModel;

    public GameRunnable(DrawingPanel drawingPanel, GameModel gameModel) {
        this.drawingPanel = drawingPanel;
        this.gameModel = gameModel;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        running = true;
        while (running && gameModel.getComputerSequence().size() < 10) {
            generateComputerSequence();
            sleep(1800L);
        }
    }

    private void generateComputerSequence() {

        gameModel.addToComputerSequence();
        for (Integer index : gameModel.getComputerSequence()) {
            drawingPanel.brighterArcModelColor(index);
            sleep(1000L);
            drawingPanel.darkerArcModelColor(index);
            sleep(200L);
        }

    }

    private void sleep(long duration) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(duration);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        }
    }

    public synchronized void setRunning(boolean running) {
        this.running = running;
    }

}
```

Remember, divide and conquer.